# wp_enqueue_style is not reading the css file

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to create a plugin. When i try to enqueue the style-sheet (css) it doesn't get read. I want to style my custom metabox. Even when i inspect element, it doesn't show the css being loaded. The link to the file is correct. I checked it with var_dump(). Any help would be handy. Thanks in advance.

> **Here is my code**

```
<?php

function sb_add_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style_tablespecs', plugins_url( 'style_tablespecs.css', __FILE__ ));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sb_add_scripts' );


function add_spec_mobile() {

    add_meta_box('spec_Mobile_1', 'Add Specs', 'html_fill_mobilespec', 'add_specs', 'normal');

}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_spec_mobile');

function html_fill_mobilespec() {
?>

<div id="input-table-spec">
<p>This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph </p>

</div>

<?php
}
```

Comment: The code looks good, but the placement could be a factor. Have you thrown a var_dump() or die() in your sb_add_scripts function to confirm that the function is even been called?

Comment: changing 'wp_enqueue_scripts' to 'admin_enqueue_scripts' in add_action fixed it. But don't know why it doesn't work otherwise.. 
Thanks for your quick answer